# Question regarding generics

Tags: c#, oop, generics

If I understand it well, then generics allows me to create types which will perform the same functionality for objects of types that are not known and will be entered when the developer uses this type, is that correct?

Comment: the questions are not clear... can you edit and clarify please?

Comment: makes more sense now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your questions which are not exactly clear, I am assuming that you don't know much about generics and are trying to understand it more...

A good link for you to read - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Generally speaking instead of doing the following

```
List listOfNumbers = new List();
listOfNumbers.Add(1); // Boxing operations 
listOfNumbers.Add("string"); // Legal as not type checked
```

You can do this

```
List<int> listOfNumbers = new List<int>();
listOfNumbers.Add(1); // No boxing operation 
listOfNumbers.Add("string"); // Illegal as its not an int type
```